# batch upload videos to youtube via command line python

Tags: python, batch-file, video, youtube

I am using the script from [youtube-upload](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload) to upload videos to my channel via the command line.
 **How can I run the code to process all files in a specific folder(s)?**
Once I saw an example on the net, showing how to batch upload videos to youtube using this same script, and also getting the titles, categories, description and tags from a csv excel file, each from a column corresponding to the file name in another column. I forgot to save this example and now I can't seem to find this or create it on my own.
by the way, I am on windows 10 environment, using the command line tool.

to upload single video, I am using this script;

```
youtube-upload \
 --title="A.S. Mutter" 
 --description="A.S. Mutter plays Beethoven" \
 --category=Music \
 --tags="mutter, beethoven" \
 --recording-date="2011-03-10T15:32:17.0Z" \
 --default-language="en" \
 --default-audio-language="en" \
 --client-secrets=client_secrets.json \
 --credentials-file=client_secrets.json \
 test.mp4
```

### update

the csv file will have the same number of columns as I will have parameters in the youtube-upload command. Let's say, there will be title, description, category, tags columns only, and of course the first column will be the file name, if needed, I will also add the location of the file.

Comment: Open a command prompt window, run `for /?` and read the output help pages. The command __FOR__ is for processing something in a loop like the lines of a text file or the files matching a pattern in a directory (tree), or ...

Comment: And are you also using some sort of csv file for the files in your folder? If so, what is the layout of the CSV file, and does each line include the video file associated with it? If not, can I just say `youtube-upload test.mp4`?

Comment: @SomethingDark I added an update to the question taking your comment into account.

Comment: I notice that the tags have a comma in them. Since "CSV" historically  stands for "comma-separated value", what delimiter will the CSV file be using, since it's not a comma?

Comment: @SomethingDark, yes, it will use, semi colon " ; " instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:: == ASSUMPTIONS ==
:: - this script is in the same directory as your CSV file
:: - your CSV lines are in the following order:
::   file_name;title;description;category;tags;recording_date
:: - Your descriptions do not contain semicolons
@echo off

set video_folder="C:\path\to\your\video\folder"

:: If your videos and csv file are in the same directory, you don't need the pushd or popd
:: Also, I couldn't get line continuation to work inside of the for loop, so everything
:: MUST be all on the same line.
pushd %video_folder%
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=;" %%A in (vids.csv) do (
    youtube-upload --title="%%~B" --description="%%~C" --category="%%~D" --tags="%%~E" --recording-date="%%~F" --default-language="en" --default-audio-language="en" --client-secrets=client-secrets.json --credentials-file=client_secrets.json "%%~A"
)
popd
pause
```

Comment: actually it works, but i need to put the variables inside quotes like this "%%D" because youtube doesn't accept it without quotes.
i have installed the python progress bar and I would like it to show the progress bar, why is it not possible here with this batch command?

Comment: If the quotes exist in the CSV file, they will be part of the variable.

Comment: Best is to state `"%%~D"`, because then it does not matter whether or not the quotes are present in the CSV file, and you always have quotes around the resulting value...

Answer (score 4):

Using a python script you would use the subprocess module to call the youtube-upload program. You could  write a little utility using this in combination with the csv module and perhaps argparse.

The core of the program is:

```
import csv
import subprocess

def upload(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile') as f:
        for info in csv.DictReader(f):
            info.update({'client-secrets':'client_secrets.json', 'credentials-file':'client_secrets.json')
            subprocess.call(['youtube-upload'] + ['--{0}="{1}"'.format(k,v) for k,v in info.items()]})
```

The CSV file should be exported from Excel so that commas are quoted. We are using a header row in the CSV to define the parameters that will be passed on the command line to youtube-upload.

The whole utility could look like this:

```
#!python
"""
Upload media files specified in a CSV file to YouTube using youtube-upload script.

CSV File exported from Excel (i.e. commas properly quoted)
First line contains upload parameters as column headers
Subsequent lines contain per media file values for the corresponding options.
e.g.
file,description,category,tags...
test.mp4,A.S. Mutter,A.S. Mutter plays Beethoven,Music,"mutter, beethoven"
etc...

"""
import csv
import subprocess

def upload(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        for info in csv.DictReader(f):
            info.update({'client-secrets':'client_secrets.json', 'credentials-file':'client_secrets.json'})
            commandline = ['youtube-upload'] + ['--{0}="{1}"'.format(k,v) for k,v in info.items()]
            #print commandline
            subprocess.call(commandline) 

def main():
    import argparse
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='youtube upload the media files specified in a CSV file')
    p.add_argument('-f', '--csvfile', default='vids.csv', 
        help='file path of CSV file containing list of media to upload')
    args = p.parse_args()

    upload(args.csvfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Once you are into Python you might like to investigate the [YouTube API which can be accessed directly from Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).

To get started I'd use the fact that `youtube-upload` could in fact be loaded as a python module, then instead of calling `subprocess` you could `import youtube-upload` and call `youtube-upload.main(commandline)`.

Comment: why do i get an invalid syntax error in line 20?
what i have to do is to have the vids.csv file and the video files in the same folder as this python script and then run this script in windows command line using : python thisscript.py
right?
I don"t have to change anything in the script??
when i run it for one file using my own code, i don't need to have the credentials and client secrets files in the same folder, the script fetches them from elsewhere. is the the case here?

Comment: @Mpondomise this script takes the path of the CSV file on the command line e.g. `--csvfile=C:\mydata\vids2.csv`  or defaults to `vids.csv` in the working directory of the executable. As it stands it expects the media files to be in the working directory of have their path in the _file_ column of the CSV spreadsheet. You could modify it by adding a directory argument to the command line arguments. the upload' method would need to add this to the file name. e.g. `info['file'] = os.path.join(r'C:\myvideos', info['file']`

Comment: @Mopondomise regarding the credentials, I am not sure how _youtube-upload_ works, it looks like they are in a file `client_secrets.json` so the same directory and path considerations apply as to the CSV and media files.

Comment: If you just want to upload videos then the batch file using _for_ that SomethingDark describes [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37036688/5002578) is a great solution. I'm presenting this python for if you want to get in and have more control on all the directories and fields etc. Using python and the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) you can do all sorts of things.

Comment: when i run it, i have this error message http://i.imgur.com/Crhh3Rz.png
i am very interested to run this python code and see it work.

Comment: @Mpondomise - you still are not specifying the location of the CSV file. You need to call the script like `python upload.py C:\my\path\to\vids.csv`

Comment: @Mpondomise, the system can not find `youtube-upload` so can't execute is as a subprocess. Make sure that it is in the windows `PATH` i.e.that it can be executed from the command line. typing the command that is passed to subprocess. Uncomment the print statement at line2

Comment: ...Uncomment the print statement at line 22 to see the command. Does it need `.exe` or to be `python youtube-upload.py` or something?