# Python youtube-upload opens file dialog box

Tags: python, youtube-api

When I type `youtube-upload --title="The Chain ~ The Guardians Of The Galaxy Vol. 2" The_Chain.mp4` onto my cmd, it opens a file dialog box. I have followed the installation of youtube-upload properly. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37036688/8342742) in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962260/batch-upload-videos-to-youtube-via-command-line-python).
a

> ```
> :: == ASSUMPTIONS ==
> :: - this script is in the same directory as your CSV file
> :: - your CSV lines are in the following order:
> ::   file_name;title;description;category;tags;recording_date
> :: - Your descriptions do not contain semicolons
> @echo off
>
> set video_folder="C:\path\to\your\video\folder"
>
> :: If your videos and csv file are in the same directory, you don't need the pushd or popd
> :: Also, I couldn't get line continuation to work inside of the for loop, so everything
> :: MUST be all on the same line.
> pushd %video_folder%
> for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=;" %%A in (vids.csv) do (
>     youtube-upload --title="%%~B" --description="%%~C" --category="%%~D" --tags="%%~E" --recording-date="%%~F" --default-language="en" --default-audio-language="en" --client-secrets=client-secrets.json --credentials-file=client_secrets.json "%%~A"
> )
> popd
> pause
> ```

Also the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047405/8342742) is useful when you are into python.

> Once you are into Python you might like to investigate the [YouTube
>   API which can be accessed directly from Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).
>
> To get started I'd use the fact that youtube-upload could in fact be
>   loaded as a python module, then instead of calling subprocess you
>   could import youtube-upload and call youtube-upload.main(commandline).

The core program will be like:

```
import csv
import subprocess

def upload(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile') as f:
        for info in csv.DictReader(f):
            info.update({'client-secrets':'client_secrets.json', 'credentials-file':'client_secrets.json')
            subprocess.call(['youtube-upload'] + ['--{0}="{1}"'.format(k,v) for k,v in info.items()]})
```

And the utility could be like this:

```
#!python
"""
Upload media files specified in a CSV file to YouTube using youtube-upload script.

CSV File exported from Excel (i.e. commas properly quoted)
First line contains upload parameters as column headers
Subsequent lines contain per media file values for the corresponding options.
e.g.
file,description,category,tags...
test.mp4,A.S. Mutter,A.S. Mutter plays Beethoven,Music,"mutter, beethoven"
etc...

"""
import csv
import subprocess

def upload(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        for info in csv.DictReader(f):
            info.update({'client-secrets':'client_secrets.json', 'credentials-file':'client_secrets.json'})
            commandline = ['youtube-upload'] + ['--{0}="{1}"'.format(k,v) for k,v in info.items()]
            #print commandline
            subprocess.call(commandline) 

def main():
    import argparse
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='youtube upload the media files specified in a CSV file')
    p.add_argument('-f', '--csvfile', default='vids.csv', 
        help='file path of CSV file containing list of media to upload')
    args = p.parse_args()

    upload(args.csvfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```